# iTextSharp: manual pagination of table by counting rows, but what if a line wraps?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to create a pdf. This pdf contains a table, which I'm creating using DirectContent. I count the rows that I write and do a `document.NewPage()` when the row count gets to 45. Everything seems to work fine **unless** any of the lines wraps to a second row. If that happens my row count will be off, and ultimately my paging will be incorrect. Does anyone have any ideas how I can work around this problem? My complete program follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using static iTextSharp.text.Font;

namespace iTextSharp_long_table
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (stream)
            using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                document.Open();

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
                table.TotalWidth = 72 * 7.5f;
                int nrows = 0;
                int topOfPage = 0;

                Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9, Font.BOLD);
                Font fontPlain = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9);
                for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)    // jobs
                {
                    if (nrows >= 45)
                    {
                        table.WriteSelectedRows(topOfPage, -1, 36, 9 * 72, writer.DirectContent);
                        document.NewPage();
                        topOfPage = table.Size;
                        nrows = 0;
                    }
                    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Job " + (i + 1).ToString(), font));
                    cell2.Border = PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER + PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER + PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(227, 235, 247);
                    cell2.Colspan = 3;
                    table.AddCell(cell2);

                    string currency = string.Format("{0:C}", Math.Round(1.23, 2));
                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currency, font));
                    cell2.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(227, 235, 247);
                    cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                    cell2.Border = PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER + PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER + PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                    table.AddCell(cell2);
                    nrows++;

                    // workitems
                    DoWorkItems(ref table, ref nrows, ref topOfPage, document, ref writer, ref fontPlain);

                    // add a blank row before the next job
                    cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                    cell2.Colspan = 4;
                    cell2.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
                    table.AddCell(cell2);
                    nrows++;
                }

                table.WriteSelectedRows(topOfPage, -1, 36, 9 * 72, writer.DirectContent);
                document.NewPage();
            }

            byte[] result = stream.GetBuffer();
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\Long Table.pdf", result);
            Process.Start(@"c:\temp\Long Table.pdf");
        }

        public static void DoWorkItems(ref PdfPTable table, ref int nrows, ref int topOfPage, 
            Document document, ref PdfWriter writer, ref Font fontPlain)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)     // workitems
            {
                if (nrows >= 45)
                {
                    table.WriteSelectedRows(topOfPage, -1, 36, 9 * 72, writer.DirectContent);
                    document.NewPage();
                    topOfPage = table.Size;
                    nrows = 0;
                }
                string str = "     - Item " + (j + 1).ToString();
                Phrase phrase = new Phrase(str, fontPlain);
                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(phrase);
                cell2.Colspan = 4;
                cell2.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
                table.AddCell(cell2);
                nrows++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you add the table using the direct content and `WriteSelectedRows` instead of adding the table to the document and letting itext split it? That reason might be important for an answer here, too.

Comment: Yes (though maybe I don't have to?). I do it because I want to start the table at a specific point on the page (in the real program, I draw an image at the top of the page).

Comment: That doesn't mean you cannot add the table to the document. Simply set the page margins so that the remaining space is where you want the table to go.

Comment: Thank you, @mkl! You cleared up a misconception I had and allowed me to solve this problem. Since I don't have to use direct content, I can just add the table to the document and let iTextSharp do the pagination. Problem solved :-).

Comment: I'll write an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is best to leave the layout details to iText, in particular for the main content that may or may not spread across pages. The only content one usually has to create the layout of is header, footer, background, and similar material.

In the case at hand it turned out in comments that the reason why the OP handled the layout details himself was:

> I do it because I want to start the table at a specific point on the page (in the real program, I draw an image at the top of the page).

But this is also possible while letting iText handle the layout: One merely has to set the page margins so that the remaining space, the space which iText uses to layout content in, is the space where one wants one's content to show.

(Beware: You have to set the margins *before* the page in question is created. In case of the first page this means in particular that you have to do this before opening the document.)

Doing so solved the OP's Problem:

> Since I don't have to use direct content, I can just add the table to the document and let iTextSharp do the pagination. Problem solved :-).